# equivalent of each() for mysql results, to mimic first loop of foreach()

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, each

I've seen in the code I'm working on, the following:

```
foreach( $mysql_result as $row ) $site_id = $row->id;
```

$mysql_result is, of course a mysql_result, so this foreach is equivalent to a while( mysql_fetch_row() )

Sometimes, the result is known to yield only one row, but the code still has a "foreach" so it *gives the impression* of being a loop through many rows.

I tried using each() but doesn't work for this.

I know I could use mysql_fetch_row(), but the code should be DB independent so I can't use DB specific functions.
Is there something like each() that works in this case just as the first iteration of foreach() ?

PS: what I do currently for readability is turn the previous example to this:

```
foreach( $mysql_result as $row ) break;
$site_id = $row->id;
```

So it's pretty obvious that the foreach will at most loop only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is instead of this:

```
foreach( $mysql_result as $row ) $site_id = $row->id;
```

Just this:

```
$site_id = $mysql_result[0]->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

> PS: what I do currently for
>   readability is turn the previous
>   example to this:
>
> foreach( $mysql_result as $row )
>   break;

Wrap that in a function so it's clear that it gets one row(and still are db independant)

```
function fetch_single_row($result) 
{
  foreach( $mysql_result as $row ) break;
  return $row;
}
```

Then your code would look like

```
$row = fetch_single_row($mysql_result);
$site_id = $row->id;
```

Now you won't have to wonder about all the strange foreach(..) break; statements all over the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one result, then you don't need to loop.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$site_id = $row['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You ould use a do loop

```
$i =0
do {
    $site_id = $mysql_result[$i++]->id;
} while ($i <= 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
if ( 1 == count( $mysql_result ) )
{
  $row = current( $mysql_result );

  // could probably also do this unless the array isn't zero-indexed
  // $row = $mysql_result[0];
}
```

Comment: I think current() fails the same way each() does. Are you sure about it? I'll try it.